# Fetch Thymeleaf Templates from Remote Location

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I want to fetch the email Template from GITHUB and use the template in my Thymeleaf configuration to send email.  I don't want to save my Template inside my JAR running at PCF. It should be on fly.

1. I was successful in fetching the HTML file from GITHUB
2. Now the HTML file is maintained as InputStream

Now the question is how use this Inputstream at TemplateResolver and set my variables and create the String value of the HTML content to send Email  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can process a `String` template like this:

```
SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();

Context ctx = new Context();
ctx.setVariable("variable", "value");

String processedTemplate = templateEngine.process("<html><div th:text='${variable}' /></html>", ctx);
System.out.println(processedTemplate);
```